# Mean and Standard Deviation with a Filter

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to find the mean and standard deviation playing time for those who play soccer and those who do not. I'm able to find these values for the soccer players but I'm getting an error when I try to add my second filter. The second filter that I want to add is PLAYERS == '2'. Can you look at my code and see where I'm going wrong ? Thanks!

```
filter(PLAYERS == '1' & PLAYERS == '2') %>%
   group_by(PLAYERS) %>%
   summarise(mean_soccer = mean(PLAYINGTIME, na.rm=TRUE),
             sd_soccer = sd(PLAYINGTIME, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
```

Comment: No one would be both "1" and "2". If you want to include both, change to `mydf %>% filter(PLAYERS %in% c("1", "2"))`

Comment: you can also replace the ``AND`` condition by ``OR`` if this is what your looking for  ``(PLAYERS == '1' | PLAYERS == '2')``

Comment: Are there values other than `1` and `2` you’re trying to exclude? If not, and you’re just trying to get means/SDs for each group, get rid of the `filter()` entirely. All you need is `group_by() %>% summarise()`.